# Can't Modify Frozen Class & Can't Determine Why Class is Frozen

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems, trailblazer

I'm working on a Ruby on Trailblazer API and I keep getting this error when I run my Rspec test suite:

`FrozenError:   can't modify frozen #<Class:NotificationCenter>: NotificationCenter`

I can't seem to determine where or how the class is being frozen. Find the file and stacktrace below for context:

#### `sftp.rb` File:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'grape'
require 'concepts'

class NotificationCenter < NotificationCenter.superclass
  module API ### <- failure occurs on this line ###
    class Notifications < Grape::API
      class Reports < Grape::API
        class Failed < Grape::API
          class Sftp < Grape::API
            resource :sftp do
              route_param :email do
                desc 'send notification to a specific user when report has failed to upload to sftp'

                params do
                  optional :test, type: Boolean, default: true
                  requires :email, type: String, coerce_with: Base64.method(:urlsafe_decode64)
                  requires :report_name, type: String
                end

                post do
                  result = run! Notification::Report::User, {}, 'email.cell' => Notification::Cell::Report::Failed::Sftp

                  handle! result
                end
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

#### Stack trace:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/resources/notifications/statements/failed_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: module API

FrozenError:
  can't modify frozen #<Class:NotificationCenter>: NotificationCenter
# ./app/resources/notifications/reports/failed/sftp.rb:7:in `<class:NotificationCenter>'
# ./app/resources/notifications/reports/failed/sftp.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
# ./app/resources/notifications/reports/failed.rb:7:in `glob'
# ./app/resources/notifications/reports/failed.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
# ./app/resources/notifications/reports.rb:7:in `glob'
# ./app/resources/notifications/reports.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
# ./app/resources/notifications.rb:7:in `glob'
# ./app/resources/notifications.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
# ./app/resources.rb:4:in `glob'
# ./app/resources.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
# ./app.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
# ./spec/resources/notifications/statements/failed_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
# /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.8.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
```

As I said earlier, I can't seem to determine where or how the class is being frozen. I traversed the stack trace to try and determine where the `NotificationCenter` class had been defined the very first time. As far as I can tell, the `sftp.rb` file above, where the error is occuring, is the first time the class is being defined. I put a `binding.pry` just below `class NotificationCenter < NotificationCenter.superclass`, and ran `NotificationCenter.frozen?`, which returned `true`.

This is strange to me because as the class is being defined, the very first time it even comes into existence (as far as I can tell), it is already frozen. Additionally, there is not a single `.freeze` in the entire repository. So the class is seemingly being frozen by some other means.

Does anyone have any idea why this might occur?

Comment: Where is this file located? I think you're running into conflict with the auto-loader, or Zeitwork as it's called internally.

Comment: `class NotificationCenter < NotificationCenter.superclass` is a *really* strange thing to be doing. What is the intent here? I'm also really confused by the extreme nesting and that every single step inherits from `Grape::API`. I'd expect a lot of those intermediate steps to be `module`.

Comment: I suspect it wants to reopen `NotificationCenter` ensuring there is no superclass mismatch. The easiest way to do that is to not have a superclass in that spot, when you reopen, Ruby does not require it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't actually write any of this code. I'm just in the process of updating the Ruby version for this application/repository. So I don't really know why anything is built the way it is. tadman, I agree it all looks very strange to me! 

@engineersmnky that's a great recommendation, I'll give that a shot. Could give me some more info at the very least. Thank you all!

Comment: Since Ruby 2.7 there is also `Module#const_source_location`. In the line above the class definition you could print `Object.const_source_location(:NotificationCenter)`.